# How do I set /pgfplots/trig format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying out pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=1.25, samples=50, /pgfplots/trig format=rad]
  \addplot[blue, thick] ({x},{sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `/pgfplots/trig format` key does not seem to work, though; I have to change my expression to `{sin(deg(x))}` to get it to calculate with x in radians, and I want my trig functions to operate in radians by default.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of pgfplots are you using?

Comment: how do I find that out? I use tikzedt

Comment: Write `\pgfversion` for TikZ version and `\pgfplotsversion` for pgfplots version after `\begin{document}`

Comment: ok, I had to switch to \documentclass[]{article} to get it to show up. pgfversion = 3.0.0, pgfplotsversion = 1.1.0

Comment: ah yes. Sorry I forgot that. I think you need at least 1.11 for that feature if I'm not mistaken

Comment: bah. :-( i'm scared to update my MiKTeX distribution, i'll just use `deg()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by updating PGFPlots v1.11 or higher (as also is mentioned in the comments).